# Create subdomain for existing website, point it at new VPS

Tags: vps, subdomain

Our company has a site, say site.com.  I would like to add a subdomain to this "test" and point it at the new VPS hosted site.  so when you go to test.site.com, it will load the site I've built on the new VPS. I was told that I would need to go to the domain info, and create an A Record for test.site.com and point it at the VPS ip_address.  However the network admin said that he won't do it because typing in the VPS ip_address doesn't resolve in the browser.  Currently, to view the VPS site, I use a url like "<random_numbers>.temporary.link".

Since typing the ipaddress in the browser doesn't resolve to the site, does that mean the A Record for the subdomain should use the "<random_numbers>.temporary.link" instead?

Also, is there anything I have to do on the VPS-end in CPanel to facilitate this?

Thanks for any info

Comment: so, what IP address does `<random_numbers>.temporary.link` resolve to? - oh, wait `temporary.link` isn't a valid domain so how does that work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by using the verb 'resolve' in the phrase ' typing in the VPS ip_address doesn't resolve in the browser'? The verb 'resolve' has a specific meaning and doesn't apply to IP addresses.

Comment: Also, questions about CPanel are off-topic here.

Comment: by "not resolve", i mean when you type in the IP it just says "connection has been reset". you can't access the site by browser with the IP. you have to use the actual link "https://<random_numbers>.temporary.link" to view the website. and yes that is a valid link, I left the random numbers out because it's my account name.

Comment: the question is, how do I create an A record to point a subdomain of an existing domain at this site, since the direct IP doesn't resolve in the browser. can you make an A record to point at the text link?

Comment: then ignore the cpanel comment.  ill rephrase. is there anything i have to do server side to facilitate this?